# WinForms AppCenter Crashes - AppCenter.Start(...) hangs

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-app-center

I have a WinForms based C# (.NET Framework 4.7.2) project that uses Microsoft.AppCenter 4.4.0 (AppCenter.Analytics and AppCenter.Crashes).

When I call `AppCenter.Start` on Windows 11 (retail), the app hangs and the call never returns:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

AppCenter.Start(ourAppSecretGuid, typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
```

Interestingly, this *doesn't* happen in a debug build *if I'm attached to the remote debugger*. The call returns (seemingly) normally.

I know that the Visual Studio debugger has some impact on how exceptions/crashes are handled in the program under test, and I suspect that is somehow interacting with the AppCenter crash-interception logic... but I still don't know specifically why this is happening or what to do about it.

**EDIT**

Here's the stack trace:

```
  mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Wait(int millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  Microsoft.AppCenter.dll!Microsoft.AppCenter.Utils.Synchronization.StatefulMutex.GetLock()
  Microsoft.AppCenter.dll!Microsoft.AppCenter.Channel.Channel.SetEnabled(bool enabled)
  Microsoft.AppCenter.dll!Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenterService.OnChannelGroupReady(Microsoft.AppCenter.Channel.IChannelGroup channelGroup, string appSecret)
  Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.dll!Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.Crashes.OnChannelGroupReady(Microsoft.AppCenter.Channel.IChannelGroup channelGroup, string appSecret)
  Microsoft.AppCenter.dll!Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.StartService(Microsoft.AppCenter.IAppCenterService service)
  Microsoft.AppCenter.dll!Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.StartInstance(System.Type[] services)
  Microsoft.AppCenter.dll!Microsoft.AppCenter.AppCenter.PlatformStart(string appSecret, System.Type[] services)
> myapp.exe!SpazzTech.App.Program.Main()
  [Native to Managed Transition]
  mscoreei.dll!_CorExeMain()
  mscoree.dll!_CorExeMain_Exported()
  kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
  ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()
```

I'm seeing this in Win 11 running in a Virtual Box VM. I'm setting up a physical Win 11 box to test against.

Comment: Works on Windows 10: `AppCenter.Start("9a51eb2e-cb68-40bc-92ac-e199e147a267", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));`

Comment: Hi there! 
@ScottSmith Could you please try to update the App Center SDK version to the latest (it is `4.4.0` for now) and try again?

@JeremyThompson I would recommend you remove `app-secret` from your code snippet to avoid any unexpected traffic. Please see [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/troubleshooting/uwp#protect-the-app-center-secret-value).

Comment: @Anastasia he's already using 4.4.0 and that's just a random Guid I copied from an Assembly file, it's not a app-secret.

Comment: What target do you use in your app?

Comment: @Anastasia - Ours is an x64 product, and I see this in both release and debug builds (though not when a debugger is actually attached)

Comment: @JeremyThompson - Yeah, our product has been shipping for Windows 10 x64 for over two years, and this hasn't been an issue.

Comment: @ScottSmith raise a Microsoft support case, given this is a bug it's unlikely Microsoft Product Support Services will charge you.

Comment: Do you use the target framework like `net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0` in your project?

Comment: @Anastasia - We use .NET Framework 4.7.2. (sorry, I left the "Framework" part out of the original post, and that matters - will edit)